# javafx application crashing while launching from netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I have a javafx application , which I am trying to run from source in NetBeans. But now the javafx application failing with jvm crash. How I can troubleshoot what is going wrong here ?

Netbean version - 8.0.1
Java - jdk1.7.0_51 -- 64 bit server VM 
OS - Windows 7 64 bit

Any idea , where to look for trouble ?

Thanks

Comment: What does the stackTrace say ?

Comment: Did you mean the crash log ? No stack trace. The JVM is getting crashed.